# Datatables: Adding an extra row on real time?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a new row to a table, after it is loaded (since I need to retrieve some data), but the new row just shows 'undefined'. It looks like this:

```
$('#example tr').each( function () {
                id = this.id.substr(4);
                var result2;
                if (id.length > 0) {
                    $.post('get_stuff.php', {id: id}, function(result) {
                        result2 = result;
                    }); 
                    oTable.fnOpen( this, result2, "info_row_");
                }
            } );
```

The above opens the new rows and writes 'undefined' in them. If, however, before the fnOpen call I add an `alert(result2)` the result is shown in the alert and then written to the row. How can I solve this?

Comment: Duplicate of every other question where somebody didn't know what AJAX was.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with jQuery datatables. You could have narrowed down your problem by abstracting that part away.

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209080/create-new-row-with-nested-tables-with-ajax-request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$.post()` request is asynchronous.

So the info is written while it is still being requested.

You could either add:

`$.ajaxSetup({async:false});` before the `.post()` call or use `.ajax()` with `async: false` option.

`.post()` is just a shorthand version of `.ajax()`

Or you could write the vakue in the success callback of the `.post()` function.

```
$.post('get_stuff.php', {id: id}, function(result) {
  //result2 = result; // don't know if you still need the result2 var somewhere else. If that's the case you should use one of the other approaches (as stated above)
  oTable.fnOpen( this, result, "info_row_");
});
```

Comment: as PeeHaa rightly pointed out `$.post` is shorthand for `$.ajax()` so our answers are functionally identical

Answer (score 2):

This will wait until the Ajax call has completed successively before executing the function.

```
$('#example tr').each( function () {
            id = this.id.substr(4);
            if (id.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'get_stuff.php', 
                    data: "id="+id, 
                    success: function(result) {
                        oTable.fnOpen( this, result, "info_row_");
                    }
                }); 

            }
        } );
```

Comment: You don't need `result2` any more.