# Create new row with nested tables with Ajax request

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to create a similar functionality to this one: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html.

The only major difference to my code is that I'm trying to get the data through Ajax, and it does not work!

The Ajax request itself is made successfuly and I can see the HTML code inside the response.

My JS Code:

```
/* Creata TableData
--------------------------------------------*/
function fnFormatDetails ( StreetVal, oTable, nTr )
{
    var sOut = $.ajax({
      url: "ajax.php",
      data: StreetVal,
      success: function(data) {

          console.log(data);
          return data;

      }
    });

    return sOut;
}

$(document).ready( function(){


    $('.table-data tbody tr td a').addClass('closed');

    var oTable = $('.table-data').dataTable({ 
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", 
        "bStateSave": false, 
        "bRetrieve": true
    });

    $('.table-data tbody tr td a').live('click', function (event) {

        var StreetVal = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
        var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;

        if( $(this).hasClass('closed') ) {

            $(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('open').html(' - ');
            oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails( StreetVal, oTable, nTr ), 'details' );

        } else {

            $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('closed').html(' + ');
            oTable.fnClose( nTr );
        }

        return false;


    });

});
```

The problem is that it is throwing an error:

> Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLTableCellElement.appendChild]
>   [Break On This Error] nNewCell.appendChild( mHtml );

at line 1776 of jquery.dataTables.js / v. 1.8.3.dev

What is the problem? Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: Can you pass 3 arguments to fnFormatDetails like that? The example shows only 2 arguments being passed, oTable and nTr.

Comment: @Greg Pettit - Why not? I think you can pass as many as you like. Can't you?

Comment: I have no idea, hence why it was formed as a question. But presumably the function is acting on what you're passing to it in a prescribed way. If you arbitrarily throw something new into it, the function might not know how to handle it.

Comment: @Greg Pettit  - just tested it. I removed my 3rd argument and script still through an error.

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767205/datatables-adding-an-extra-row-on-real-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually returning "sOut.responseText" instead of sOut in fnFormatDetails seems to work.

Comment: Can you give any example, please?

Comment: What do you mean by example ? I changed the last line of fnFormatDetails function to "return sOut.responseText;" and it worked. But I did it during debug, so you have to add async:false to jquery Ajax call to see it working.

Comment: I have updated the test file `http://seefeld.pl/test/` - it does not through an error any more, but does not display the data either. Copy of the file here: `www.seefeld.pl/test/jQuery%20DataTables%20with%20hidden%20rows.zip`

Comment: Sorry - that was because of the previous change I have made. Your solution does work! Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nTr is a JS node, not a Jquery element. You could try setting nTr like this:

```
var nTr = $(this).parent("tr")[0];
```

Also, try putting "async: false" in the Ajax request to make sure its' completed before calling the function.

Comment: Unfortunately, with those changes the scripts return the same error msg.

Answer (score 0):

Working JS code:

```
function fnFormatDetails ( StreetVal, oTable, nTr )
{
    var sOut = $.ajax({
      url: "ajax.php",
      async: false, // added 
      data: StreetVal,
      success: function(data) {
          return data;            
      }
    });

    return sOut.responseText; / changed form `return sOut`
}
```